# Encrypt (disk level) on Database Server MS SQL 2008

Tags: windows, security, encryption, bitlocker, disk-encryption

Has anyone tried to encrpyt disk drives for a database server running WANSync?

We used Arcserve WANSync for HA to our DB servers and we are planning to encrypt both the primary and secondary disks using a Bitlocker.

We would like to know the impact when all disks were encrypted on our database servers:

What will be the impact on MS SQL 2008?
When failover happened are there any impact?
Any observations to those who experience encrypting drives on a server running WANSync High Availability?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Servers encrypted with bitlocker need to have a TPM or network unlock server to make sure they can come online in the event of a reboot or power failure.

Comment: Thanks Appleoddity again. Do you have any idea about servers that runs HA (we used Arcserve WANSync) and together the disks was fully encrypted? I have read some FAQ answers that Bitlocker has no effect on how users or applications connect to SQL Server, in short the Bitlocker will just work fine on any servers. but if HA servers with bitlocker for ex. "ServerHAmain" failvover to "ServerHAreplica" are the process of WANSync would not have any problem? I hope someone can give me some insight. Thank you.